# Is it possible to use kerberos authentication with visual studio code remote?

Tags: vscode-remote

We use kerberos authentication for connecting to our on-prem computing environment. I'd like to use visual studio code remote to do development directly on that server. Based on [this section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_enabling-alternate-ssh-authentication-methods) in the vscode remote documentation, it seems like it's possible to use password-based authentication, which works for me, but it would be nice if I could use existing kerberos authentication, instead of having to type my password every time I start up a vscode session.

I've tried searching through the documentation above, but I can't figure out if kerberos is supported. I would like to know if I should *respectfully* raise an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release).

Answer (score 7):

## Update from March 2020.

I've used plain PuTTY (plink.exe) to connect from VsCode with kerberos using those simple steps.

1. Define a session inside PuTTY that opens a ssh shell to your remote machine, save it as `remote`.
2. Create "C:\Users\< youruser >\ssh.bat" with the contents below. You need echo to fool VsCode that it's OpenSSH client.

   ```sh
   echo OpenSSH
   SET mypath=%~dp0
   powershell %mypath%ssh.ps1 %*
   ```

   3. Create powershell script `ssh.ps1` in the same folder with these contents:

```sh
$ArgArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Args
$ind = $ArgArray.IndexOf("-F")
if ($ind -ge 0) {
  $ArgArray.RemoveAt($ind)
  $ArgArray.RemoveAt($ind)
}
Write-Host $ArgArray
& 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe' $ArgArray
```

Theoretically you can write it in batch language but I did not want to suffer.

4. Set "remote.SSH.path" setting in VsCode to your `ssh.bat` path.
5. Finally, add ssh host configuration in vscode and use session name as host:

```
 Host remote
     HostName remote
     User <you ssh user>
```

Comment: For those not familiar with powershell, the bat file should really read `powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %~dp0ssh.ps1 %*`. This still works (and is needed) August 2020 1.48.2, the only catch was I had was I needed to increase the ssh timeout (due to my ssh server being slow). Thanks for this!

Comment: can confirm this method worked for me today using vscode 1.59.0 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/250#issuecomment-896215333

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible. There is a [feature request about this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/250) which has been closed because it will not be implemented in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Closed as out of scope :(

Answer (score 1):

My tweak on @Roman's batch script

```
@echo off

for %%x in (%*) do (
  REM Handle -V
  IF "%%x" == "-V" GOTO :version
  REM Handle vscode remote as special for plink only
  IF "%%x" == "remote" GOTO :plink
)
REM use the built in ssh by default
GOTO :default_ssh

:version
echo OpenSSH
GOTO :eof

:plink
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %~dp0ssh.ps1 %*
GOTO :eof

:default_ssh
ssh.exe %*
GOTO :eof
```

It allows you to only use plink for the vscode "remote" server name (I have my reasons), so everything behaves as normal unless you choose hostname `remote`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Kerberos-integrated SSH client for Windows it should work.
I'm not sure if the Microsoft openSSH for Windows 10 / Server 2019 is Kerberos-integrated or not. The one that comes with Git for Windows is not.

If you have a Kerberos-enabled version of PuTTY, you can make a small hack to use plink.

**This broke with the June release**

Create the file **C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\ssh.bat**
The file location will be different if VScode is installed in your home directory.
Put the following in the file. Adjust the plink path to your PuTTY directory.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Centrify\Centrify PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -K %*
```

Comment: Hi, can you suggest the version that works and where to download it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very [tiny wrapper](https://github.com/benok/ssh2plink) for plink.exe.

(It just fakes version string with openssl's and remove unsupported '-T' option.)

I don't use with kerberos but it might help with settings like [aviso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781481/26736).

Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented on [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2280111/roman) answer, but it appears I do not have enough reputation.

I followed his steps, except that I put the plink.exe path for "remote.SSH.path" instead of the "ssh.bat". My path to plink.exe is simply "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe".

I tried multiple things and to date, this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: If you call plink directly, the first thing vscode does is run `${ssh} -V` and if it does not match the regex `/OpenSSH/` then it ignores your custom ssh, and searches its own defaults. So what you are actually doing is still using the "not plink" ssh client

Answer (score 0):

Another tweek for @Roman's and @Andy's `ssh.bat` script that worked for me; I specify several hosts to use plink.

```
@echo off

if %1 == -V GOTO :version
if %4 == "myFirst.remoteHost.address" GOTO :plink
if %4 == "mySecond.remoteHost.address" GOTO :plink
if %4 == "myThird.remoteHost.address" GOTO :plink

REM use the built in ssh by default
GOTO :default_ssh

:version
echo OpenSSH
GOTO :eof

:plink
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %~dp0ssh.ps1 %*
GOTO :eof

:default_ssh
ssh.exe %*
GOTO :eof
```